# Can we make different style in same text tag in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have a text like this: **User ID:** 12345
I want to put it in only a text tag. `<Text>UserID: 12345</Text>`
But both part will be same style if I do that. So can we make only "UserID" bold?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use *nested* `Text` in order to do that

```
    <Text>
        <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>UserID:</Text>12345
    </Text>
```

Comment: nested tag work great! It also uses parent style too. :)

Answer (score 1):

sure you can use an other tag inside of your tag like this:
    **UserID:** 12345

`<Text><Text style={styles.bold}>UserID:</Text> 12345</Text>`

`var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bold: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
};`

Comment: I got error: "Invariant Violation: View config not found for name b". This is not HTML.

Comment: my bad your using react native 
so in react native view html tag not working